# Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.TestEndToEndLatency

Tags: apache-kafka, benchmarking

I'm trying to run a benchmark on kakfa following [this article](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines) and using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ueokande/b96eadd798fff852551b80962862bfb3) but when I run

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.TestEndToEndLatency localhost:9092 localhost:2181 test 5000
```

this is returned

```
Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.TestEndToEndLatency
```

Can someone help with this?

Kafka version: [2.5.0](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.5.0/kafka_2.12-2.5.0.tgz)

Answer (score 2):

The Class was renamed to `EndToEndLatency`, with that it should work ([relevant commit](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/c60125cf4b983de958685cdcf10e7bab9813b119)).

The arguments also changed slightly (most importantly, you no longer specify the ZooKeeper DNS name and port):

```sh
$ bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.EndToEndLatency --help
USAGE: java kafka.tools.EndToEndLatency$ broker_list topic num_messages producer_acks message_size_bytes [optional] properties_file
```

So an example usage would be (a properties file is needed for a TLS connection):

```sh
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.EndToEndLatency kafka.cluster.org:9093 test-topic 100000 1 3072 ~/config
```

The properties to put into the file (`~/config` here) for a TLS connection:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/tmp/kafka/cluster.keystore.p12
ssl.keystore.password=keystore-pass
ssl.key.password=key-pass
```

Comment: Depending on the use case you want to test, you could either access port 443 (over the Ingress, simulating traffic from outside the cluster) or 9093 (simulating traffic within the cluster).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to pass the consumer `group.id` to this? Or is `test-group-(timestamp)` hardcoded?